# Looking for SQL Server 2000 DTS Components

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to upgrade a very old SQL Server 200 to SQL Server 2008 R2. We have many DTS Packages that I need to migrate over and view using SSMS 2008. I know I need the sql server 2000 dts designer components but every Microsoft Link I try fails.

Does anyone happen to have this that they can link to for a download of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything I've heard suggests that you're much better off rewriting your DTS jobs as SSIS packages from scratch. "Migrating" doesn't always work well and then you're stuck rewriting the broken packages anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fair warning, this is tricky.  I get it working about 9/10 times these days.

FYI First install the 2005 backward compatibility components, then the DTS components.

I believe both are located here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793 but no guarantees.